# Prototyping tubular components

Tags: prototyping

I'd like to mock up a quick prototype of a chassis assembly for a type of cart, which, in production, would be composed of CNC bent aluminum extrusions (hollow, approximately 5/8" circular profile), and connected using plastic joints. I'm wondering if anyone could recommend methods for prototyping the tubular components.

I'm considering using PVC, but I would like to use something I could bend and shape angles into relatively easily.

Comment: use metal conduit.

Comment: If weight isn't critical in the prototype, copper pipe and common plumbing tools (pipe cutter, bender, unions, tees, solder) would be one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT - I've solved this issue after a bit of searching for similar application requirements, so I'll post my solution:*

Applying a bit of heat using a heat gun to sand-filled PVC pipe allowed me to slowly bend the pipe into my desired shape. The sand prevents the PVC from collapsing inward as it is bent.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer